# Wanting to make a 2D bouncy floating island In Unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to coding and I am currently wanting to create a floating island that bounces up and down on collision with the player. Note, currently in order for the island to go down on collision, I have a rigidbody on both the player and the island, with the island's gravity scale set to 0 and mass to about 5. This is what I have so far: using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

```
public class island : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb;

    public bool GroundTouch = false;

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        GroundTouch = true;


    }

    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
    {

        GroundTouch = false;

    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (GroundTouch == false) {

            StartCoroutine(canGoUp());
        }
    }


    IEnumerator canGoUp()
    {
        functionCalled = false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        functionCalled = true;
    }


    bool functionCalled = false;

    void Update()
    {

        if (!functionCalled)
        {
            Bounce();

        }
    }

    void Bounce()
    {
        rb.AddForce(transform.up * 20);
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this bounce have to interact physically? If not you might want an animation instead.

Comment: Thanks for your response! If the bounce were an animation, would it's collider move with it?

Comment: I'm no expert but I think so: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1204815/how-to-update-2d-colliders-with-spirte-animation.html

Comment: Thanks! I'll do some research on how to start the animation when it collides with the player.